# Unity - Make Object disappear for a while and show again

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make to game object that can disappear for a certain time. I wrote this code but it doesn't work at all.

Here is my code:

```
public class Fire : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] int decreaseHealth;

    [SerializeField] GameObject handlerObject;

    GameHandler handler;

    void Start()
    {
        decreaseHealth = 10;

        handler = handlerObject.GetComponent<GameHandler>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            StartCoroutine(ShowAndHide(this.gameObject, 2.0f)); // 2 second
            // Decrease Health
            handler.decreaseHealth(decreaseHealth);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShowAndHide(GameObject go, float delay)
    {
        go.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        go.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 2):

In general from your description it sounds like you rather want to first `SetActive(false)` and then after a delay `SetActive(true)`! Currently you have it the other way round.

---

I would **not** use a Coroutine here since it hinders you to fully deactivate the object. Because of you deactivate the object the Coroutine doesn't run anymore.

---

Rather use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) which also works on a deactivated object.

Btw also rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html) instead of directly comparing strings using `==`. It is very slightly faster but more importantly `CompareTag` throws an exception if the given tag name is misspelled or doesn't exist at all. Using `==` would hide this "bug" and cost you development time and nerves ;)

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        HideAndShow(2.0f); // 2 second
        // Decrease Health
        handler.decreaseHealth(decreaseHealth);
    }
}

private void HideAndShow(float delay)
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);

    // Call Show after delay seconds
    Invoke(nameof(Show), delay);
}

private void Show ()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    StartCoroutine(ShowAndHide(this.gameObject, 2.0f)); // 2 second
    //Decrese Health
    handler.decreaseHealth(decreaseHealth);
    Destroy(this.gameObject); // <- this
```

You destroyed the game-object you want to hide and show while it is hiding and showing.

Coroutines run asynchronously with the other codes, so if you want to destroy it after it has hidden itself, do it in the coroutine instead, like so:

```
IEnumerator ShowAndHide(GameObject go, float delay)
{
    go.SetActive(true);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    go.SetActive(false);
    Destroy(go); // Destroy after it has hidden itself.
}
```

Comment: but when press i play the game, it doesnt looping. i want the output is hide, wait a second, unhide

Comment: @RakaAryaPratama what do you mean by `it doesn't looping`? Also, if you wanted it to hide first, use `.SetActive(false);` first, then set it to `true` to show it later.

Comment: @Kaynn if you do that though the Coroutine will stop running so the object is never re-activated.